# Access: Search Multiple Table and Return Unique Customer Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I am a complete noob with databases but have managed to design one for my friend who runs an insurance agency.  I am almost finished but I just need to be able to enter a search field.

Basically, I have a customer form with all the customer's contact details and then subforms showing the different types of insurance policies (motor, home, medical, etc)  The customer form links to a customer table, the subforms link to tables (motor, home, medical,etc., one table per subform)  All tables are linked through the field CustID

What I need to do is to search each subform for a unique policy number then return the customer form relating to that policy number.  Or to paraphrase; search for the policy number amongst all the tables (motor, home, medical, etc), locate the CustID then bring up the Customer Form relating to that CustID.

Any help would be appreciated as I have spent days searching the web trying queries and union queries and haven't found any responses which would bring up the form.  I am obviously missing something

Comment: Does your main form show all customers, or only one customer at a time? I suggest that you add either a combobox or a text box on the main form. If combobox, populate will ALL policy numbers, then add some VBA code to filter your form when a selection is made. If using a textbox, you can have it narrow your filter as each character is typed in. Yes, you can search the subforms to find a policy number, but that seems backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Wayne for trying to help, in the end I kept plodding through and sorted it out.

I wanted to report back what I had done.  I have shown all my steps below, you never know this may help another user:

I created a Union query that called all the policy numbers together from my different policy tables:

*SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Motor.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Motor ON Customer_Details.CustID = Motor.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Home.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Home ON Customer_Details.CustID = Home.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Liability.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Liability ON Customer_Details.CustID = Liability.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Marine.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Marine ON Customer_Details.CustID = Marine.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Medical.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Medical ON Customer_Details.CustID = Medical.CustID
UNION SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Pet.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Pet ON Customer_Details.CustID = Pet.CustID;*

I made a Combo box (Combo41) with the source being my Union Query (UnionQueryPolicyNo)
Adjusted the number of columns and width of columns with 0cm to hide the Customer ID column

Then created a "Select Policy No." button
with the following "On Click" Event Code:

*Private Sub Command43_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command43_Click
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    stDocName = "CustomerBase" 
    stLinkCriteria = "[CustID]=" & Me![Combo41]
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
Exit_Command43_Click:
    Exit Sub
Err_Command43_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command43_Click
End Sub*

Now I can enter the policy number in the Combo Box and click the Select Policy No button and it brings up the customer form relating to that policy number.  Yey!!

So that you can see the layout of the code I have attached cropped screenshots.

[UnionQueryPolicyNo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOWq.jpg)

[Select Policy No. Button Event Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozSoT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Menu form (switchboard) which is where I want to run the search from this has an alphabetically sorted table showing all the customers and I have added a button which allows me to select any one customer and display the Customer Record Form.

The Customer Record Form shows all the customer details including tabbed sub forms showing any policies he has bought.

I have attached screen shots of both these forms.  Everything on the forms works perfectly except the Policy No. Look Up on the Menu form: when I enter a valid policy number it returns a new (blank) customer record form instead of the customer's record who has that policy number.

I have written the following Queries, which return the correct result:

**Query 1**:
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Motor.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Motor ON Customer_Details.CustID = Motor.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Home.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Home ON Customer_Details.CustID = Home.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Liability.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Liability ON Customer_Details.CustID = Liability.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Marine.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Marine ON Customer_Details.CustID = Marine.CustID
UNION
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Medical.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Medical ON Customer_Details.CustID = Medical.CustID
UNION SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, Pet.Policy_Quote_No
FROM Customer_Details RIGHT JOIN Pet ON Customer_Details.CustID = Pet.CustID;

and

**Query 2:**
SELECT Customer_Details.CustID, UnionQueryPolicyNo.Policy_Quote_No
FROM UnionQueryPolicyNo INNER JOIN Customer_Details ON UnionQueryPolicyNo.CustID=Customer_Details.CustID
WHERE (((UnionQueryPolicyNo.Policy_Quote_No)=[Forms]![Menu]![Text8]));

So I think it is just down to the code for the button which at the moment I have as a Macro:

Action: Open Form
Form Name: CustomerBase
View: Form
Where:  [PolicyLookuponUnionQuery]![CustID]=[Customer_Details]![CustID]

[CustomerBase Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aphh4.jpg)

[Menu Form (Switchboard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr4tG.jpg)

I hope I have managed to explain this better and thank you for your help.

Comment: From looking at your switchboard, I believe the rightmost column is the Policy #. If so, you need to change all of your queries that have a 'WHERE' clause to enclose the value in quotes (because the field is not numeric). Also, what is the 'Record Source' for the customer form? Do you add a filter, or do you have code to refresh the recordset? Does 'Query 2' return the correct value? What code is behind the button click? I will now take a longer look at this and reply soon.

Comment: Thanks Wayne.  No the rightmost column is the telephone number.  All the items in the list on the Switchboard are from the same table (Customer_Details).  The policy numbers are all held on separate tables then displayed in tabbed subforms on the CustomerBase Form.  The Refresh button at the top will refresh the list.  In the end I deleted Query 2 completely and went a different way.